# How Can I Add The iframe Code Of The Github Code To My Site?

Tags: webserver

I need some guidance on running GitHub code on my site. I've downloaded the files and uploaded them to my site's file manager. However, when I try to open the page, I encounter the following error
[image: This is the screenshot of the page]

How can i convert this to the page which will fully work.

I am tried multiple times, Please suggest me the easy solution.

Comment: This isn't a github problem... But can't tell what tags would be better.

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks for the reply, but do you know what is this error and how can i solve it.

Comment: It doesn't look like an error per se. The webserver is just returning the directory contents for the things you've uploaded. You may need to add is configure the default document your webserver should serve. But you've geven us very little to work with here so it's almost I possible to give you any directive guidance.